# calculating big O for a while loop binary search

Tags: java, c++, big-o

I need to find out how efficient the following code is as compared to linear search:

```
int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int min = 0;

while(min != max) {
    int check = (max + min) / 2;
    if(isLessThanX(check)) {
        min = check;
    } else {
        max = check;
    }
}
```

linear search is O(n), however... if i understand the above code, it is a binary search(i think) now my GUESS is that the big O of this is:   O(n/2)   <-- is that correct ?

Comment: O(N/2) is not a valid Big-O. If something was O(N/2) you would simply call it O(N).

Comment: This is binary search, assuming `isLessThanX` work OK, it's **O(log Integer.MAX_VALUE)**. It appear as you are guessing a number between `0 and max integer`.

Comment: There is no such thing like `O(n/2)`. Parameter under Big-O is `c.n` and generally we ignore `c`. Please note that `c > 0`

Comment: Are you sure the number can't be less than 0?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes. Big-O is an approximation of the number of operations to complete a task. If it can be less than 0, it would state that the operation can be completed in less than 0 operations (which is hard to state because it makes no sense)

Comment: @Vlad274 I was questioning whether `int min = 0;` should be `int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` (which is negative).

Comment: @elliottFrisch I'm sorry, I read it as a follow up to Shravan40's comment. Yes, that is a very valid question

Comment: C'mon dude, if ur gonna c/p mah code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667150/new-to-programming-how-to-determine-unknown-x-with-islessthanx-method - you could at least accept the answer. ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`O(n/2)` is exactly the same as `O(n)`. In general, `O(f(n)) == O(k*f(n))` for any function of n, `f` and any constant `k`.

The algorithm you posted **does** use a binary search, which is `O(log(n))`. If you have 8 items, it will take 3 iterations for your algorithm to run. 16 will take 4, 32 will take 5...Do you see the pattern?

Comment: The base of `log` is irrelevant in the big-O notation, as long as it's a constant > 1.

Comment: @fabian That is exactly the same as saying that in something like `O(n^2)` the exponent is irrelevant as long as it's a constant > 1.

Comment: The logarithm base *is* irrelevant (with some restrictions) because `log_a(x) = log_b(x) * log_a(b)`.

Comment: @shmedfred Yes it is, do you want an explanation ?

Comment: @Nelxiost After some research, it looks like 9th grade algebra was lost on me. Thank you for the correction.